# leaflet.Control.extension causing issues with react-leaflet eventHandlers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm developing a React Leaflet application.  I extended the base leaflet control API and pass context through `React.useContext()` hook into the secondary render.  The issue I'm having is  the react-leaflet `eventHandlers` hook doesn't register the `click={()=>...}`  event.

**MapRoot:**

maproot compiles all the layers into the container and is passed to the `ReactDOM.render()`

```js
function MapRoot() {
    const { position, zoom } = useContext(Controller);
    const basemapUrl = 'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
    const basemapAttribution = '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>';
    return (
        <MapContainer className='mapContainer' center={position} zoom={zoom} scrollWheelZoom={true} zoomControl={false}>
            <LayersControl>
                <MapExtensions />
                <BaseProducts />
                <TileLayer url={basemapUrl} attribution={basemapAttribution} />;
            </LayersControl>
        </MapContainer>
    );
}
```

**LeafletMapExtensions:**

`L.Control` is extended with a LeafletMapExtensions layer

```js
L.Control.LeafletMapExtensions= L.Control.extend({
    onAdd: (map) => {
        var div = L.DomUtil.create('span');
        div.setAttribute('id', 'leafletExtensions');
        div.style.height = '100vh';
        div.style.width = '100vw';
        div.style.margin = 0;
        div.style.padding = 0;
        div.style.cursor = 'pointer';
        return div;
    },
});

L.control.leafletMapExtensions= (options) => new L.Control.LeafletMapExtensions(options);
```

**ExtensionController** && **MapExtensions**

`ExtensionController` is added to `MapExtensions` which is called in a second order `ReactDOM.render`

```js
function ExtensionController({ ...props }) {

    return (
            <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
                <SidebarController {...props} />
                <ToolbarControll {...props} />
                <TimeControl {...props} />
            </div>
    );
}

export default function MapExtensions(props) {

    const { navIcons } = useContext(controllerContext);
    const map = useMap();

    useEffect(() => L.control.mapExtension().addTo(map), [map]);
    useEffect(() => {
        const _id = document.getElementById('leafletExtensions');
        const handleMouseOver = (e) => {
            map.dragging.disable();
            map.touchZoom.disable();
            map.doubleClickZoom.disable();
            map.scrollWheelZoom.disable();
            return null;
        };
        const handleMouseOut = (e) => {
            map.dragging.enable();
            map.touchZoom.enable();
            map.doubleClickZoom.enable();
            map.scrollWheelZoom.enable();
            return null;
        };

        ReactDOM.render(<ExtensionController onMouseOver={handleMouseOver} onMouseOut={handleMouseOut} navIcons={navIcons} />, _id);
    }, [navIcons, map]);
    return null;
}
```

**BaseProducts:**

In initial render the `eventHandlers` are not recognized when extension is active.  Any suggestions on activating the render.

```js
const BaseProducts = ({ coordinates })=>
     <Polygon positions={coordinates} eventHandlers={{ click: (e) => console.log(e) }} />
```

Comment: Can you share why you chose to have a secondary render? This is not conventional and not the way React was designed to be used. There is likely a better solution. Are you having trouble positioning Control's?

Comment: ```var div = L.DomUtil.create('span');``` is created after the basemap is loaded, and added to the control layer.  Then I call reactDOM render on the span element.  I ended up figuring out my issue was to deal with the css in the span element. I was rendering a higher priority element full height and width on top of the basemap which was overwriting some of the base controls.